# $stateProvider not working properly in Angularjs + Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have scaffold ionic project with generator-ionic and created a blank project. I have tried to add a state but the app doesnt load the template defined in any of the state.

here is my app.js

```
'use strict';
    angular.module('IonicCarOPedia', ['ionic'])
    .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider

      .state('main', {
        url: '/main',
        templateUrl: 'view/main-view.html',
        controller:'MainCtrl1'
      });

    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');

  })

.controller('MainCtrl1', function(){
    console.log("main ctrl alled")
  });
```

Here is index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>"IonicCarOPedia"</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/ionic/release/css/ionic.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  </head>

  <body ng-app="IonicCarOPedia">

    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/collide/collide.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/release/js/ionic.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/release/js/ionic-angular.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

            <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>    

    <nav-bar type="bar-positive"
             animation="nav-title-slide-ios7"
             back-button-type="button-icon"
             back-button-icon="ion-ios7-arrow-back"></nav-bar>

    <nav-view></nav-view>
</body>
</html>
```

and main-view.html:

```
<view title="'Employees'">

  <div class="bar bar-subheader item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
      <i class="icon ion-ios7-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    </label>
  </div>

</view>
```

What ever i do template isnt shown, not even the MainCtrl1 is called.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok Seems like some silly mistake, but I did tried it before which never worked, but its working now.

I have changed ionic elements: `nav-bar` to `ion-nav-bar`, `nav-view` to `ion-nav-view` and `view` to `ion-view` and that worked now.